# List of (unsolved) complexity problems arising from PL

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, pl.programming-languages, big-list, open-problem

What are some major, open computational complexity problems that arise from programming languages, especially program analysis and compilation? I am looking for problems on the lines of "the time complexity of Hindley-Milner type inference" or "the time complexity of 0CFA" (though both are solved problems).

Comment: Why the vote to close?  If this question is "too broad", tons of other questions on this site should be closed.

Comment: One I’m interested (but I am not sure if it is unsolved) is using (non-closed) Beta distance of lambda terms from a ground term as a measure of complexity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pippenger's (1) from 1996 shows that (under some assumptions)  **strict** (CBV) functional programming languages are asympotically slower than imperative languages.  It is open whether Pippenger's result can be generalised to **lazy** functional languages, as was pointed out in (2).

Pippenger imposes two simplifying assumptions (on-line computation, and a certain atomicity of input). It is open whether 
they can be removed.  Pippenger conjectures that it can be done, but warns: *"[s]uch a result [...] seems far beyond the reach of currently available methods in computational complexity theory"*.

See also Campbell's answer in (3), and  Ben-Amram's notes (4).

---

<sup>1. N. Pippenger, *[Pure Versus Impure Lisp](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/Pure%20Versus%20Impure%20LISP.pdf)*.</sup>

<sup>2. R. Bird, G. Jones, O. De Moor, *[More haste, less speed: lazy versus
    eager evaluation](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/richard.bird/online/BirdJonesDeMoor1997More.pdf)*.</sup>

<sup>3. Stack Overflow, *[Efficiency of purely functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990464/efficiency-of-purely-functional-programming)*.</sup>

<sup>4. A. M. Ben-Amram, *Notes on Pippenger's Comparison of Pure and Impure LISP*.</sup>